# Error putting table inside makebox

Tags: tables

I'm getting the following error when I put my table inside a makebox.

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.62     }
>        Try typing  <return>  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
> ```

I'm using the makebox to adjust the page margins to the left, otherwise it will not fit correctly in the page. It shows correctly the page, but I'm still getting this error. I'd like to know why this error occurs and how to fix it. Right below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,     % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    % french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    % spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}



\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Características dos corpora de pacientes}
    \makebox[26cm]{
        \begin{center}
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2,5cm}|p{1,5cm}|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|p{2cm}|p{1,5cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Nome} & \textbf{Idioma} & \textbf{Quantidade de documentos} & \textbf{Tipos de documentos} & \textbf{Aplicações} & \textbf{De acesso gratuito?} & \textbf{É anotado?} & \textbf{Está desidentificado?}   \\
            \hline
            i2b2 & Inglês & 1,2 bilhão & Prontuários de pacientes internados, documentos financeiros, exames laboratoriais e sumários de alta. & Desidentificação, extração classificação, identificação e normalização de dados diversos & Sim, mediante autorização & Possui ambos dados anotados e não anotados & Sim \\
            \hline
            CCHMC & Inglês & 3273 & Radiologia renal e pulmonar e cartas de suicídio & Identificação de doenças de acordo com a CID-9 e análise de sentimentos & Sim para uso acadêmico e mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            MIMIC-III & Inglês & 61293 & Admissões de pacientes em CTI e admissões de pacientes neonatais & Ensino, aprendizado de máquina, predição de dados e análise semântica & Sim, mediante a autorização e ter feito um curso & Não & Sim \\
            \hline
            BioScope & Inglês & 3236 & Resumos de documentos médicos, artigos completos de medicina e textos livres de radiologia & Estudar níveis de asserção & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            THYME & Inglês & 1254 & Registros clínicos de pacientes com câncer no cólon & Identificar relações temporais & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            CPRD & Inglês & 11 milhões & Prontuários de pacientes & Diversas & Não & Não & Sim \\
            \hline
            THIN & Inglês & $\cong$ 3,9 milhões & Prontuários longitudinais de pacientes & Diversas & N/A & Não & Sim \\
            \hline
            Stockholm EPR Corpus & Sueco & 2 milhões & Prontuários de pacientes & desidentificação, pseudo-anonimização, identificação de incertezas, negações e asserções, anotações clínicas, classificação de documentos e relações temporais & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            \textit{EMC Dutch Clinical Corpus} & Holandês & 7500 & Prontuários longitudinais de pacientes, receituários, laudos de radiologia e sumários de alta & Relações temporais, negação e análise de experiências dos usuários & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            \textit{Turku Clinical Treebank and Propbank} & Finlandês & 8 & Documentos de enfermagem & Análise de dependência de estruturas linguísticas & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            \textit{Synthethic Clinical Text Corpus} & Alemão & 55 & Anotações clínicas e sumários de alta & Reconhecimento de entidade mencionada & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
            \hline
            \textit{Chinese Electronic Medical Corpus} & Chinês & 255 & Prontuários de admissão & Reconhecimento de entidade mencionada & Sim & Sim & Sim \\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    }
    \label{tab:caraccorpora}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: To fix the symptom: remove the `\begin{center}... \end{center}`. By default the contents of `\makebox` is centered within the box. The `\begin{center}... \end{center}` will _not_ help you align the box relative to the page anyway.

Comment: For temporarily making the margins thinner, I would instead suggest using either the package `changepage` or `fullwidth`.

Comment: Couldn't you make the whole table narrower to ensure it fits into the textwidth?  Probably you can choose different column types that take up less space. For example, do you really need a fixed width for the second column? Wouldn't a simple l type column also work?

Comment: Issue: Don't use commas to specify real lengths. So, instead of `2,5cm`, you need `2.5cm`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved removing the **\begin{center}** block inside the makebox as stated by [Willie Wong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119/willie-wong).

According to him:

> By default the contents of \makebox is centered within the box. The \begin{center}... \end{center} will not help you align the box relative to the page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I took a liberty to redesign your table according to my taste. To my opinion it now has more "professional" look. Of course, if you more prefer cells' contents in jail :-), you can replace horizontal rules from `booktabs` with `\hline` and add vertical lines.

Since your table is really huge, it is reasonable to consider to spread it over two landscape oriented pages. For this you in following MWE is used `longtable`. Beside it, for prettify of table, are used the packages `threeparttablex` (for table notes) and `booktabs` (for table's horizontal rules) too:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small\linespread{.84}\selectfont
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
%% Arrange for "longtable" to take up full width of text block
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{TableNotes}[para,raggedright]\footnotesize
\item[a]    QD:  Quantidade de Documentos
\item[b]    ED:  Está Desidentificado
\end{TableNotes}    

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    R{2.2cm} l R{2cm} R{4.5cm} R{5cm} R{4cm} R{2.5cm} l   
                  }
\caption{Características dos corpora de pacientes}
\label{tab:caraccorpora}    \\
    \toprule
\textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Idioma} & \textbf{QD\tnote{a}}
                & \textbf{Tipos de documentos} & \textbf{Aplicações}
                & \textbf{De acesso gratuito?} & \textbf{É anotado?}
                & \textbf{ED\tnote{b}\ \ ?}     \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Características dos corpora de pacientes (cont.)}    \\
    \toprule
\textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Idioma} & \textbf{QD\tnote{a}}
                & \textbf{Tipos de documentos} & \textbf{Aplicações}
                & \textbf{De acesso gratuito?} & \textbf{É anotado?}
                & \textbf{ED\tnote{b}\ \  ?}     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[-3pt]
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\insertTableNotes   \\
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{Continued on the next page}} 
\endfoot
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% table body
i2b2 & Inglês & 1,2 bilhão & Prontuários de pacientes internados, documentos financeiros, exames laboratoriais e sumários de alta. & Desidentificação, extração classificação, identificação e normalização de dados diversos & Sim, mediante autorização & Possui ambos dados anotados e não anotados & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
CCHMC & Inglês & 3273 & Radiologia renal e pulmonar e cartas de suicídio & Identificação de doenças de acordo com a CID-9 e análise de sentimentos & Sim para uso acadêmico e mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
MIMIC-III & Inglês & 61293 & Admissões de pacientes em CTI e admissões de pacientes neonatais & Ensino, aprendizado de máquina, predição de dados e análise semântica & Sim, mediante a autorização e ter feito um curso & Não & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
BioScope & Inglês & 3236 & Resumos de documentos médicos, artigos completos de medicina e textos livres de radiologia & Estudar níveis de asserção & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
THYME & Inglês & 1254 & Registros clínicos de pacientes com câncer no cólon & Identificar relações temporais & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
CPRD & Inglês & 11 milhões & Prontuários de pacientes & Diversas & Não & Não & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
THIN & Inglês & $\cong$ 3,9 milhões & Prontuários longitudinais de pacientes & Diversas & N/A & Não & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
Stockholm EPR Corpus & Sueco & 2 milhões & Prontuários de pacientes & desidentificação, pseudo-anonimização, identificação de incertezas, negações e asserções, anotações clínicas, classificação de documentos e relações temporais & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
\textit{EMC Dutch Clinical Corpus} & Holandês & 7500 & Prontuários longitudinais de pacientes, receituários, laudos de radiologia e sumários de alta & Relações temporais, negação e análise de experiências dos usuários & Sim, mediante requisição & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
\textit{Turku Clinical Treebank and Propbank} & Finlandês & 8 & Documentos de enfermagem & Análise de dependência de estruturas linguísticas & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
\textit{Synthethic Clinical Text Corpus} & Alemão & 55 & Anotações clínicas e sumários de alta & Reconhecimento de entidade mencionada & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
    \addlinespace
\textit{Chinese Electronic Medical Corpus} & Chinês & 255 & Prontuários de admissão & Reconhecimento de entidade mencionada & Sim & Sim & Sim \\
\end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
%
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have more more vertical spaces between rows, you can add to `\addlinespace` option `[<verical space>]`. For example:

```
\addlinespace[5pt]
```

Note: in `makebox` you can not included structured text as tables are. Its use for enlarge typing ares is fragile. For such purposes is better to use `adjustwidth` macro from the `changepage` package. In above example this possibility is not exploited.